# Getting div elements by .val element with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a script that generates div ids once a drop down box is clicked as shown below. The div id is actually generated by the value of the item id. I can get the value but dont know how to add it.
So basically it should be something like $('#itemsupdate2').load('index.php/sales #item ` (item id goes here...

I just cant get it to work.
 I can get the value by adding

var item = $('input[name=item]').fieldValue();

this works and i can get the value in an alert box. I am not sure how to do a load with this value. What I am trying to do is shown below.

$('#itemsupdate2').load('index.php/sales #item "+ item[0]+"').fadeIn('slow');

```
<div class="itemsupdate">

<div id="item1">
sample text 1   
</div>

<div id="item8">
1guiness150.004 
</div>

<div id="item9">
1999999.009 
</div>
```

Comment: In valid HTML, IDs cannot start with a number. Also, if you are using jQuery, don't use `.getElementById(id)`, use `$("#"+id)`

Comment: Sorry but it's a little hard to follow, what you're actually looking for.  

You want to click on a dropdown box item and...
a. It unhides the relevant div?
b. It adds html content to a div?
- if so, where from? database, server side code?

Answer (score 1):

The ".val()" method has nothing to do with "id" values.  What you're looking for is ".attr()":

```
var theId = $(whatever).attr('id');
```

Now, you've got another problem. The "id" values  need to look like identifiers. Thus, "9" won't work.  You could use something like "_9" or whatever.

Comment: @JCOC611 no, it shouldn't.  The result of calling "$(something)" is a jQuery object, and that doesn't have an "id" property as you suggest. Perhaps you meant, `$(whatever).get(0).id` or `$(whatever)[0].id`, both of which would work.

Comment: thanks for reply. how would I add that attr function value to a document get element by id function. regards.

Comment: the equivalent to `.attr` in normal DOM is `.getAttribute`, but you should use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').bind('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('.itemsupdate').html('<div id="' + val +'">contents of the div</div>');
});
```

This will add the div to `div.itemsupdate`.

Then you can access it later like this : `$('#' + $('select').val());`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I get the value by adding   var item = $('input[name=item]').fieldValue(); this works and i can get the value in an alert box. I am not sure how to do a load with this value. What I am trying to do is shown below.

$('#itemsupdate2').load('index.php/sales #"+ item[0]+"').fadeIn('slow');

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns the value of the selected object. This works great on textareas and inputs, but not on divs. Use `.text()` instead to get the text element, or use `.html()` to get the full html structure within the div. In your example, you use ids to identificate your divs. So why don't you use this id selector #?

```
$('#1').text(); // returns 'sample text 1'
$('#1').text('new text'); // will change the divs content with 'new text'
$('#1').text('text before '+$('#1').text()+' text after') // will insert 'text before' before the content and add 'text after' after the divs content: text before sample text 1 text after
```